# Is there a way to reopen the login windows that i've closed?

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to create a socket chat, and it is working for me. My problem is that I am trying to implement an option to log out and come back up with the login window, which is in the bar menu. I have tried several ways to reopen this window.

The code is in spanish. but i think it's understandable

This is the code for the client:

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext as scroll
from pymysql import Error
from pymysql import IntegrityError
import pymysql as sql
import conexion

class VentanaLogin:
    def __init__(self, ventana):
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.ventana.title('Iniciar sesión')
        self.database = conexion.Database()
        
        # --- Frame Login ---
        loginFrame = Frame(self.ventana, bg='grey8')
        loginFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 480
        anchoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventana.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Entrada y boton de login ---
        tituloLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Programa de chat online', font=('Arial', 20), bg='grey8', fg='white', bd=0)
        tituloLabel.pack(pady=50)
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su nombre de usuario', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.usuarioEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.usuarioEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        self.usuarioEntry.focus()
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su contraseña', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.contraseñaEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0, show='*')
        self.contraseñaEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        loginBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Iniciar sesión', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.login(self))
        loginBoton.pack(pady=(10,0))
        registerLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='¿No tienes una cuenta?', bg='grey13', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10), bd=0)
        registerLabel.pack(pady=(30,10))
        registerBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Registrarse', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.registro(self))
        registerBoton.pack()

        # --- Tecla inicion de sesión ---
        self.usuarioEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)
        self.contraseñaEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)

    def login(self, event):
        usuario = self.usuarioEntry.get()
        contraseña = self.contraseñaEntry.get()
        parametros = (usuario, contraseña)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE nombre = %s AND contraseña = %s'
        peticion = self.database.consulta(query, parametros)
        usuarioLogin = ''
        contraseñaLogin = ''
        for i in peticion:
            usuarioLogin = i[1]
            contraseñaLogin = i[2]
        
        if usuario == usuarioLogin and contraseña == contraseñaLogin:
            if usuario != '' or contraseña != '':
                messagebox.showinfo('Iniciar sesión', 'Ha ingresado con éxito')
                tk = Tk()
                ventanaMain = VentanaMain(tk, usuario)
                self.ventana.withdraw()
                tk.mainloop()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Ingrese los campos requeridos')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')
    
    def registro(self, event):
        tk = Tk()
        ventanaRegistro = VentanaRegistro(tk)

class VentanaRegistro:
    def __init__(self, ventana):
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.ventana.title('Registro')
        self.ventana.resizable(0,0)
        self.database = conexion.Database()

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 450
        anchoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventana.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Frame register ---
        datosFrame = Frame(self.ventana, bg='grey8')
        datosFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        # --- Entrada y boton de registro ---
        tituloLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Registro de usuario', font=('Arial', 20), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        tituloLabel.pack(pady=30)
        nombreLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su nombre',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        nombreLabel.pack()
        self.nombreEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.nombreEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        self.nombreEntry.focus()
        contraseñaLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su contraseña',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.contraseñaEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0, show='*')
        self.contraseñaEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        correoLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su correo electrónico',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        correoLabel.pack()
        self.correoEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.correoEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        registroBoton = Button(datosFrame, text='Confirmar registro', bg='white', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.registarUsuario(self))
        registroBoton.pack(pady=5)

        # --- Teclas para registro ---
        self.nombreEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)
        self.contraseñaEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)
        self.correoEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)

    def registarUsuario(self, event):
        try:
            usuario = self.nombreEntry.get()
            contraseña = self.contraseñaEntry.get()
            correo = self.correoEntry.get()

            # --- Todos los campos deben estar completados ---
            if usuario == '' or contraseña == '' or correo == '':
                messagebox.showerror('Registro', 'Ingrese los campos requeridos')
            else:
                # --- Query INSERT --- 
                parametros = (usuario, contraseña, correo)
                query = 'INSERT INTO USUARIOS (nombre, contraseña, correo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
                self.database.consulta(query, parametros)
                messagebox.showinfo('Registro', 'Usuario registrado exitosamente')
                self.ventana.destroy()
        except IntegrityError:
            messagebox.showerror('Registro', 'Ya existe una cuenta con este nombre.')
        
class VentanaMain:
    def __init__(self, ventana, usuario):
        self.ventana = ventana
        self.usuario = usuario
        self.ventana.title('Chat')
        self.ventana.resizable(0,0)

        # --- Frame main ---
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.ventana, bg='grey8')
        self.mainFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 550
        anchoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventana.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Texto del chat ---
        self.texto = scroll.ScrolledText(self.mainFrame)
        self.texto.pack(padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.textoLabel = Label(self.mainFrame, text='Escribir mensaje', font=('Arial', 12), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        self.textoLabel.pack()
        self.textoEntry = Entry(self.mainFrame, font=('Arial', 12), bd=0, width=30)
        self.textoEntry.pack(pady=5)
        self.textoEntry.focus()
        self.textoButton = Button(self.mainFrame, text='Enviar', font=('Arial', 12), bg='white', fg='grey8', bd=0, width=20, command=lambda:self.enviarMensaje(self))
        self.textoButton.pack(pady=5)

        # --- Menus ---
        self.menu = Menu(self.mainFrame)
        self.ventana.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.sesionMenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Sesión', menu=self.sesionMenu)
        self.sesionMenu.add_command(label='Cerrar sesión', command=self.cerrarSesión)
        self.archivoMenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=self.archivoMenu)
        self.sesionMenu.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.salirPrograma)
    
        self.textoEntry.bind('<Return>', self.enviarMensaje)

        try:
            # --- Conexión servidor ---
            self.socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5050))

            # --- Threads ---
            self.hiloRecibir = Thread(target=self.recibirMensaje)
            self.hiloRecibir.start()
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'El servidor no se encuentra activo actualmente. Intente en otro momento')
            self.ventana.destroy()
            self.ventana.protocol('WM_DELETEN_WINDOW', self.procesoFinalizado)

    def enviarMensaje(self, event):
        mensaje = f'{self.usuario}: {self.textoEntry.get()}'
        self.socket.send(mensaje.encode('utf-8'))
        self.textoEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.texto.insert(INSERT, mensaje + '\n')
    
    def recibirMensaje(self):
        self.texto.config(state='normal')
        while True:
            try:
                mensaje = self.socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if mensaje == '@username':
                    self.socket.send(self.usuario.encode('utf-8'))
                elif mensaje == '@otroDispositivo':
                    messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'Ya has iniciado sesión al servidor')
                    self.ventana.destroy()
                    self.hiloRecibir.join()
                elif mensaje == '@error':
                    messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'El servidor ha sido desconectado')
                    self.ventana.destroy()
                    self.hiloRecibir.join()
                else:
                    self.texto.insert(INSERT, mensaje + '\n')
            except:
                break
    def cerrarSesión(self):    
        # --- Here i'm trying to resolve this problem ---
        tk = Tk()
        ventanaLogin = VentanaLogin(tk)
        self.salirPrograma()



    def salirPrograma(self):
        self.socket.send('@desconexion'.encode('utf-8'))
        self.ventana.destroy()
        self.hiloRecibir.join()

tk = Tk()
ventanaLogin = VentanaLogin(tk)
tk.mainloop()
```

I already have a method to exit the program by pressing the "Exit" menu. For the "Logout" menu I created the method "cerrarSesion", open the login window and close the main window, but it just closes and nothing appears.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114). For help in Spanish, try [es.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this little example for a friend asking how to display a login window in tkinter.

I came up with this

**start.py**

```
from gui import GUI

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

**gui.py**

```
import sys
import tkinter

import security
from security import Security


def _check_user(user: str, password: str) -> bool:
    if user == 'test' and password == 'test':
        return True
    return False


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.minsize(600, 300)
        self._create_main_window()
        self._show_login_window()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def authorize(self, user, password):
        if _check_user(user, password):
            self._show_main_window()
        else:
            security.show_alert_bad_login()

    def on_closing(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        sys.exit(0)

    def _show_main_window(self):
        self.login_window.destroy()
        self.root.deiconify()

    def _show_login_window(self):
        self.root.wm_withdraw()
        self.login_window = tkinter.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.login = Security(self, self.login_window)

    def _create_main_window(self):
        tkinter.Label(text='I am the main window').pack()
        tkinter.Button(text='Show login window', command=self._show_login_window).pack()
```

**security.py**

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox


def show_alert_bad_login():
    tkinter.messagebox.showerror(title='Wrong username or password',
                                 message='Please check your username and password')


class Security(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, maingui, window: tkinter.Toplevel):
        super().__init__()
        self.maingui = maingui
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("Login")
        self.window.minsize(600, 300)
        self.user = tkinter.StringVar(self.window)
        self.password = tkinter.StringVar(self.window)
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.maingui.on_closing)

        self._create_window()

    def _create_window(self):
        user_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        user_frame.pack()
        tkinter.Label(user_frame, text='User').pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
        tkinter.Entry(user_frame, textvariable=self.user).pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

        password_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.window)
        password_frame.pack()
        tkinter.Label(password_frame, text='Password').pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
        tkinter.Entry(password_frame, textvariable=self.password, show='*').pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

        tkinter.Button(self.window, text='login', command=self._authorize).pack()

    def _authorize(self):
        self.maingui.authorize(self.user.get(), self.password.get())
```

The basic idea is to define the main window (not the login window) in this case `self._create_main_window()`

At the point where the login window is shown, in this case `self._show_login_window()` the main window is hidden and the login window is shown as TopWindow.

Later, if you ever need your login window again you can just call the function `self._show_login_window()` and the main window gets hidden again to show the login window.

I didn't test this extensivly, but it might help understand the idea.